# Using DB.requestDone() to force database connections back into connection pool

Tags: java, mongodb, grails-2.0

I have a grails application that uses a quartz job to automatically augment documents with data supplied from an external service. The quartz job uses a non-transactional Service to query and update documents from mongodb. The actual querying and updating uses mongo's native driver (no GORM). The quartz job and Service do not return database connections to the connection pool resulting in the error "Connection wait timeout" once all connections have been consumed.

I can fix the problem by adding a call to DB.requestDone() after querying and updating in the spawned thread. I am not sure about the ramifications of using requestDone for this purpose.

Are there negative consequences for calling requestDone without ever calling requestStart?

Are there any threading issues with requestStart/requestDone. For example, what happens if another thread is in the middle of querying Mongo when requestDone is called?

Is there a better way to ensure a database connection is returned to the connection pool?

FYI, I tried adding cursor.close() but that did not resolve the problem.